# How to get 1 digit interger number in a double number in Postgres SQL?

Tags: postgresql, int, rounding

In Postgres SQL:

Is it possible to get 1 digit number from a double number?

For example:

I have **27/10 = 2.7**

I WANT TO GET the number "2" only (as number not string)

I tried to convert 2.7 into integer but it will be rounded into 3.

How can I get the number 2 in 2.7 as the number.

Thanks for all answer.

-------EDITED----------

I found the floor() to do that.

My successful result is "**SELECT FLOOR(column_name/10) as A FROM table_name**"

I change the number 2.7 for the column_name/10 (the column_name is the column contains data which is in double type)

Hope to help everyone about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[trunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) function will truncate number to given number of decimals:

```
select trunc(2.7, 0);
 trunc
-------
     2
(1 row)
```

Comment: That was perfect but when I want to do change the number 2.7 with the data in column like "column_name/10" (column_name is the column with data is in double type). It was error. So I found the floor() to do that. My successful result is "SELECT FLOOR(column_name/10) as A
FROM table_name" - I will edit my post. Thank you guy.

Answer (score 0):

`27/10` will give result as  `2` without any func.

```
 select  27/10::numeric  
        ,27/10::real
        , 27/10 as the_result_you_need
```